# Adding ng-style attribute via jQuery, angular not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Here's a plunker demonstrating the problem : http://plnkr.co/edit/1ceWH9o2WNVnUUoWE6Gm

The code :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    console.log('yeah');
    var header = $('#weird');
    console.log(header);
    header.attr("ng-style", "{'background-color' : 'red'}")
});
```

It adds the ng-style attribute, but angular doesn't know about it, so it's never applied.

This is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do, I'm trying to add an ng-style attribute to every square in the chess board generated by [chessboard.js](http://chessboardjs.com/). I'm doing that by adding the ng-style attribute to every square inside of the compile function in the same way I add the ng-style attribute to the header. If there's a better way to do this, I'd love to know about it. If not, how can I get angular to update when the ng-style attributes are added?

I've read about `$scope`, `$digest`, and `$apply`, and I've tried playing around with them, but haven't been able to figure it out. What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: DOM manipulation should be handled in directive link functions rather than controllers. Also directive elements inherently use jquery lite.  I recommend looking into that.

Comment: I have moved it into the link function, still the same problem unfortunately. I don't think using jQuery lite instead of jQuery would change anything.

Comment: This is the wrong way to go about it. Add the ngStyle and bind it to a conditional espression. You shouldnt dynamically add the attribute

Comment: I have a reason for it. I'm using chessboard.js, which generates the board. I do intend on binding ng-style to a conditional expression, but I still have the same problem, since the board is generated by chessboard.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how exactly the directive is working, but in case of `ngStyle` you may need to recompile an element:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $compile) {
    console.log('yeah');
    var header = $('#weird');
    console.log(header);
    header.attr("ng-style", "{'background-color' : 'red'}");
    $compile(header)($scope);
});
```

`$apply` is commonly proposed when Angular is mixed with plain JS/jQuery, but it makes sense only when scope bindings need updating, it's not the case. Moreover, it makes sense when async callback stuff takes place, but scope changes that happen during controller constructor function are applied (there's no magic that distinguishes angular and non-angular stuff there, so '$apply already in progress' comes up if you trigger the digest when you don't have to).

I assume you're using jQuery intentionally, and I could spare you the 'angular-hates-jquery-selectors-bad-bad-you-re-doing-it-wrong' humdrum.